# How to show a search box inside a list form field

Tags: jform, joomla-3.4, form-fields-types

How to show a search box inside a 'list' type of form field?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to load chosen plugin to style list box fields like this.

Load chosen plugin first in your form layout file so that it can add style to your select boxes

```
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');
```

Add following class name to your form field (optional if you want to color it as mandatory field)

```
class="chzn-color-state"
```

To render the field on your form page:

```
<div class="control-group">
   <div class="control-label">
      <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('fieldname'); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="controls">
     <?php echo $this->form->getInput('fieldname'); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: The search box will be shown inside the listbox if there are 10 or more options inside it. See the below sample jQuery code that will be added by Joomla.

```
jQuery('select').chosen({"disable_search_threshold":10,
```

To override it, change your chosen loading code to following:

```
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select', null, array('disable_search_threshold'=>1));
```

Comment: I already have this included and it doesn't show the search box inside the list.

Comment: What is the type of form field you are using in your form filter xml file?

Comment: `list` the problem is not inside the filter.  Inside the filter the list shows the search box.  But when I show a similar `list` type of field in the form using `getControlGroup` doesn't show the search box.

Comment: I guess the number of options inside the listbox is less than 10. The search box automatically shows if its more than 10.

Comment: See my answer now, to know how you can override it

Comment: :-) you are correct.  If the items are more than 10 it shows the search box.... I dont want to override anything. Add this in your answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer